# Active Directory Won't Authenticate

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-authentication

Something is really buggy with our Active Directory here at our company. We can query and ping everything just fine. The time is correct. We have restarted both of our Domain Controllers. We also use a Remote product called "DameWare" and we can't log on to our remote systems as we usually do, we can only log on with the local administrator accounts. If we try logging with our DomainAdmin accounts we get a error "The token supplied to the function is invalid." We also can't access Sharepoint or any other Intranet sites, unless we log in as the Administrator.
We are stumped! Please help!

Comment: Have you recently set up SSL? Or do you use SSL and the certificate is configured correctly/in date? Is date and time correct on the entire network - all servers and client computers?

Comment: All the SSL certificates looks correct. I just double checked them along with the dates. Date and time on the entire network is also correct!